# json for the dummies

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm working with asp.net. What the following files for?

```
-json.js
-json2.js
-jsonp.js
```

So far, I've been able to serialize an object and get it to the page. What can these files do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [Mr. Crockfords github](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

json2.js: This file creates a JSON property in the global object, if there 
isn't already one, setting its value to an object containing a stringify
method and a parse method. The parse method uses the eval method to do the
parsing, guarding it with several regular expressions to defend against
accidental code execution hazards. On current browsers, this file does nothing,
prefering the built-in JSON object.

json.js: This file does everything that json2.js does. It also adds a
toJSONString method and a parseJSON method to Object.prototype. Use of this
file is not recommended.